# Sonata admin 3 : extends template gives following error “Variable ”base_template“ does not exist”

Tags: symfony, sonata-admin, sonata

When I try to extend a template I have this issue:

> Variable "base_template" does not exist.

Here is my code:

```
{% extends base_template %}

{% block javascripts %}
    {{ parent() }}

{% endblock %}

{% block content %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: I think that's because variable "base_template" does not exist. What's your question?

Comment: yes i known but i think this varibale is exist by default in sonataAdmin, no ?

Comment: I don't have that many experience with Sonata, but according to your error message, the variable doesn't exist. Have you tried to find out why? Please show some effort before asking  here.

Comment: i found the issue
the problem is in the version 3.25.0 of sonataAdmin
i'am back to version 2.22 and all it's ok
Thanks for your response

Comment: It's being worked on. See https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataAdminBundle/pull/4772

Answer (score 0):

Please use 3.24.0, 3.25.0 and 3.25.1 have regressions.

Please wait for the next release!

thank you!